# How do I put Roman numeral in a document?(lyx)

Tags: lyx, roman-numerals

I just found that I could type roman numerals through insert-Special character-symbol, but want a shortcut. How can I type roman numeral more easily?

Comment: Smell to XY question. Where you want the Roman numerals? In plaint text, in sections, in   first book pages, in tables, ....?  The best solution could be different in each case, and in several cases will be not  inserting a special symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take the example of Ⅷ. LyX converts it into the LaTeX code `\mbox{VIII}`. You have two options:

1. You can just paste the Roman numerals in directly. Try it by copying the Ⅷ character (it is viewed as one character) and pasting it into LyX.
2. You can just copy/paste LyX box insets. This leads to the same LaTeX code (and thus PDF), but there will be a LyX box inset, which takes up more space. But from a usability perspective it is easy. You just copy/paste and replace the contents with the new roman numeral you want. To do this option, either copy the text (from *outside* of LyX) `\mbox{VIII}` and in LyX go to Edit > Paste Special > Paste From LaTeX; or in LyX go to Insert > Box > Frameless and then right-click on it and go to settings and uncheck width.